# Where is OnLevelWasLoaded on Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this new unity version, I think SceneManager is used. But I cant find how to do on level was loaded with SceneManager.

The old way :

```
void OnLevelWasLoaded(){
// do something
}
```

When I try the old way I get this:

> OnLevelWasLoaded was found on MusicManager
>   This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
>   Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

I dont know how to use

```
SceneManager.sceneLoaded();
```

Dont know what to pass...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to `sceneLoaded` as an event.

Register `sceneLoaded` event in the `Start()` or `Awake()` function.

```
SceneManager.sceneLoaded += this.OnLoadCallback;
```

The `OnLoadCallback` function will then be called when scene is loaded.

The `OnLoadCallback` function signature:

```
void OnLoadCallback(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
{

}
```

Comment: Why did they even change... I dont understand why do i need to do `+=` ??

Comment: I still don't understand why do i need to do `+=`.But it works.Thanks

Comment: `+=` is used to subscribe to an event.`-=` is used to unsubscribe to an event. Please learn the basic C# stuff before using Unity. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events) is a tutorial for events and delegates.

Comment: This is not working for me, the callback is never called

Comment: @MikeB This question explains how to subscribe to the `OnLoadCallback` function and solved OP's problem. Please create a new question if it does not work for you then link this answer as something you have tried. Also mention your Unity version in that post.

Comment: @Programmer - Your attitude is disheartening and unbecoming of a programmer. Your comment is also misleading. += and -= are operator overloads. I would not include that as "basic C# stuff" considering the way in which they are overloaded is purely a Unity implementation and has nothing to do with C# as a language. Please think before you comment.

Comment: @JonathanWalker "disheartening"? If that's what I wanted to do, I wouldn't have provided a tutorial link to help OP understand that. My comment is not misleading. It is true that `+=` and `-=` are used for many other purposes but this answer is about subscribing to an event so I only talked about that. *You seem offended by almost everything in this answer and comment but that's fine with me*. Notice how I added "please" in front of that statement. You need basic C# knowledge to make games with Unity and I tell this to people depending on the question or comment they post.

Comment: @Programmer - Then please do edit your comment to correctly refer to "basic Unity C# stuff". It's still misleading. Your tutorial is for Unity, not C# as a language - which is far more vast than the small subset Unity focuses on. You've also mistaken striving for correctness with being offended, but I can understand how someone may do that.

Comment: @JonathanWalker You can't edit a comment after 5 minutes and that comment has been here for 2 years until you found it yesterday. Unity is an engine that uses C# for scripting and most stuff are done the-same way like basic C# app. The link I provided shows how to create `delegate` and `event` and subscribe to them which can be done in any C# app. You can keep calling it misleading but if OP knew this, he would have known how to use `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` even when there is no doc. There are also other tutorials on the page I linked to help OP get started.

Comment: Can you give a sample what we can do **OnLoadCallBack** function

Comment: i just call this function, done nothing about the parameters **ReportScoreLocal(GameController.instance.GetHighScore());**

Comment: *"what we can do OnLoadCallBack function"* Not sure what your question is

Answer (score 3):

This is well explained in [this post](https://answers.unity.com/answers/1236899/view.html):

> The old way:
>
> ```
>  void OnLevelWasLoaded (int level)
>  {
>  //Do Something
>  }
> ```
>
> The new way:
>
> ```
>      using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
>              void OnEnable()
>              {
>               //Tell our 'OnLevelFinishedLoading' function to start listening for a scene change as soon as this script is enabled.
>                  SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelFinishedLoading;
>              }
>
>              void OnDisable()
>              {
>              //Tell our 'OnLevelFinishedLoading' function to stop listening for a scene change as soon as this script is disabled.
> //Remember to always have an unsubscription for every delegate you
>   subscribe to!
>                  SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelFinishedLoading;
>              }
>
>              void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
>              {
>                  Debug.Log("Level Loaded");
>                  Debug.Log(scene.name);
>                  Debug.Log(mode);
>              }
> ```
>
> Note that 'OnLevelFinishedLoading' is a name that I've made up. You
>   can name your method whatever you like.
>
> What you're seeing in the `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` functions are
>   delegate subscriptions. This simply means that we are setting a
>   function of our choice (in this case, `OnLevelFinishedLoading`) to
>   listen to the `SceneManager` for a level change.
>
> Also note, that since this delegate has two parameters (`Scene` and
>   `SceneMode`), that you must include those two parameters as well - even
>   if you don't plan on using that information in your function.