# Unity throwing: Request error (error): UnityEditor.AsyncHTTPClient:Done(State, Int32) error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am running unity 5.3.4p4 version.But I get an error like Request error (error):  UnityEditor.AsyncHTTPClient:Done(State, Int32) for couple of days while I open unity .

Though it's not creating any problem right now,
but I want to get rid of this error.

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: Googling says it's likely an error on Unity's servers. Does it pop up when you search in the asset store or something simliar? When are you getting it? [Someone](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/request-error-error-unityeditor-asynchttpclient-done-state-int32.459092/), if this isn't you, just got the same issue.

Comment: No, when I open unity , I get the  error  frequently while running any project or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This usually happens when there is a problem with Unity's Asset server.

You can temporray disable that error by going to:

*Edit* **-->** *Preferences...* **-->** then disable *Show Asset Store search hits*.

Restart Unity after this. If this does not resolve your issue, please update Unity because 5.3 is really old.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :). It has worked and I didn't update unity @Programmer

Comment: Unity 5.3 isn't THAT old and they have yet to resolve the issue with OnLevelWasLoaded()s replacement event not being called all the time and not happening at the same time.

Comment: @MikeB I realized you made  a similar comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801130/unity-5-onlevelwasloaded#comment67853624_39801575) but failed to reply to it. This problem has been fixed. There is nothing wrong with  `OnLevelWasLoaded`. Read [this](http://www.wenyu-wu.com/blogs/unity-when-using-onlevelwasloaded-and-dontdestroyonload-together/) post to see it's behavior.  Just to let you know that Unity 5.3 can't run on some Android devices. I believe Android (5.0) due to new permission introduced,

Comment: Plus all the problems fixed since then. Unity 5.3 is really old. Not even sure if it can generate compile-able iOS project files with the latest Xcode.

Comment: OnLevelWasLoaded does work fine but it has been deprecated and the replacements timing is sufficiently different that it does not work in my application. At the time I decided that, after wasting two days trying to get the SceneManager event to work for me I would roll back, stick with 5.3 and wait to see if anything was changed. My thought is to finish the branch I am on then I'll rewrite the offending code in whatever the most recent version is at that time.

Comment: Oh and @Programmer Good memory, that comment was back in October

Comment: Lol not a good memory but thanks. Just Google "`OnLevelWasLoaded`" and that post in the 5th result and the 1st stackoverflow link. Make sure you do backup before upgrading anything in the future.

Comment: @Programmer I think you misunderstand. I am currently using OnLevelWasLoaded and it works perfectly. In Unity 5.4 they deprecated OnLevelWasLoaded and want you to subscribe to a callback using the SceneManager. The callbacks timing is different that OnLevelWasLoaded and does not work in my application. I will have to completely rewite a section of my game to make it work without using a scene loaded notification. (I wish I could PM users, this feels off topic here but there is no alternative)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137394/discussion-between-mike-b-and-programmer).

Comment: by the way I use Unity 2017.1.0f3 which is their latest version as of this comment and it STILL throws that http error if you don't disable the show asset store hits, so it has nothing to do with the version of unity its something they broke on their asset server.

Comment: I know that it has nothing to do with the version number that's why the first line in my answer says *"This usually happens when there is a problem with Unity's Asset server."*. Although I believe that Unity can write a better code to prevent throwing that error but they haven't done so. Note that any comment under this post is talking about a different problem.

Comment: Worked for me Unity 5.6.3p1 (after installing the security patch)