# Unity cannot set ActiveScene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm switching scenes:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
Debug.Log("Current scene: " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Debug says:

```
Current scene: Scene1
```

I've tried this also:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
StartCoroutine(WaitUntilEndOfFrame());
Debug.Log("Current scene: " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

private IEnumerator WaitUntilEndOfFrame() {

yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

}
```

Still says

```
Current scene: Scene1.
```

I've tried SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildId(1));

I've tried launching that as a coroutine, I've tried that and waiting for 5 seconds. Still ActiveScene is Scene1, even though the scene changes in Unity. Nothing changes the active scene...

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your *Scene Settings*.

Comment: @Programmer I'm not sure what you're referring to. Render settings? They've changed UI logic a bit, could you please clarify what you're looking for? Sorry for inconvenience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");` is called, the scene does not unload until next frame. So, if `Debug.Log("Current scene: " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` called right after that, it will return the name of the current scene not that scene is just loaded.

Even when you use coroutine and wait for a frame, that wouldn't work either because after a frame, the script and *GameObject* will be destroyed and your `Debug.Log("Current scene: " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` won't get to run.

Don't call `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` right after `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");`. Put `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` in the `Awake` or `Start` function and you will be able to get scene name after the scene loads.

**EDIT:**

Another thing to do to is subscribe to the [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801575/3785314) event. Now, call `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");`. When scene is done loading, the registered function should be called.

```
void Start()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
}

void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += this.OnLoadCallback;
}

private void OnLoadCallback(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Current scene: " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

---

Finally, if you don't add the scenes to the *Build Settings*, `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");` won't even work so your current scene will still be your current scene. Below is how to add scenes to the *Build Settings*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way to procedurally wait until until the level is loaded using a coroutine or any other method? I would prefer to preserve my linear flow of logic, but if that's not the case then I'll re-write it.  P.S.: Even Update() won't work?

Comment: Nope the `Update()` function can even be used for that. Like I said, even coroutine cannot do that. Look at the **Edit** I made in my answer about `SceneManager.sceneLoaded`. That's another way to do it.