# How to change scene in Unity when called from listener?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as I've been told on here, I cannot call for the scene change from the Update() function. Okay, how do I implement the scene changing logic otherwise?

So for example, inside of the Update() I'm listening for the responses & requests from my server:

```
private void Update() {

// A bunch of parsing stuff

switch (DataFromServer) {

   case "ServerAllowedSceneChange":

      SceneManager.LoadScene(DataFromServer[2]);
      break;

   }

}
```

That's how I see the implementation logic, however, that's not how Unity appears to do it. Could someone advice on how to do something similar in the way that Unity will work :)

The downside of this method, which actually kind of works, is that the scene is not ready to be worked with when I call it that way. Right after the scene change call, I try to access objects that do not exist yet. And all checks for level finished loading do not work.

So that if we go back to the code example, if I do this:

```
switch (DataFromServer) {

   case "ServerAllowedSceneChange":

      SceneManager.LoadScene(DataFromServer[2]);
      GameObject objectFromSceneImSwithcingTo = GameObject.Find("objectFromSceneImSwithcingTo").gameObject;
      break;

   }
```

I get the NullReference error from Unity.

Comment: Where did you read that you can't do it from update? Pleas read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html). It also explain that scene will be loaded at start of new frame.

Comment: @Logman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420223/unity-cannot-set-activescene/43420980   Don't get me wrong - it loads the new scene, but I have no access to objects in it yet. I tried waiting for end of frame, and wait for whatever amount of seconds launching a coroutine - doesn't work

Comment: Please read answer you provided ;). You can't access new scene properties as when new scene is loaded old scene is already destroyed.

Comment: That's right, but the script is not being destroyed on load, and the object is from the new scene. So by the time I call for access, the scene should have been already loaded and the script running in "DontDestroyOnLoad" section

Comment: To clarify you can't access new scene after LoadScene as scene is not actually loaded at this time. And if I remember right coroutines are stopped after scene changed even if you create object with DontDestroyOnLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SceneManager API has events you can subscribe for scene changes. For example:

```
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

  void OnEnable() 
  {
      SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
  }

  void OnDisable() 
  {
      SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
  }

  private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) 
  {
      // all objects are loaded, call other methods
  }
```

Comment: Works like a clock! Thanks! Now I get how OnEnable works, what about the OnDisable? Is it used for unloading the old scene? If yes, then how?

Comment: OnDisable is called when the gameobject **is about to be** destroyed/set inactive and can be used for any cleanup code.