# Unity, how to de/activated components in other scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is the following.
I'm in the main menu scene, and there are 2 buttons: one playerVSplayer and the other VScpu.
Now, I want enable/disable some component in the scene that will be loaded when one of the buttons will be pressed.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public void PlayerVsPlayer()
{
    GameObject[] objs = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("First Level").GetRootGameObjects();
    foreach(GameObject o in objs)
    {
        if(o.gameObject.tag == "--Gameplay")
        {
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<StaticPlayerCtr_p2>().enabled = true;
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AI>().enabled = false;
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false; 
        }
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene("First Level");
}

public void VsCPU()
{
    GameObject[] objs = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("First Level").GetRootGameObjects();
    foreach (GameObject o in objs)
    {
        if (o.gameObject.tag == "--Gameplay")
        {
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<StaticPlayerCtr_p2>().enabled = false;
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AI>().enabled = true;
            o.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene("First Level");
}

public void QuitGame()
{
    Application.Quit();
}
```

That's the error:

> ArgumentException: The scene is invalid.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't added "First Level" to the build index, or that you have misspelled it.

Comment: Two things as a suggestion.
1. Keep your PvP and PvC gameplay in separated scenes.
2. Create a singleton or static class to hold the scene names there to avaid typos and maintain type sefty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity cannot set ActiveScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420223/unity-cannot-set-activescene)

Comment: You should load the scene first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot access scenes GameObjects from other scenes.

If you wish to have two different scenes depending on an option (Here it would be PvP & PvCpu) you must create two different scenes. Then depending on which option is chosen let's say PvP and PvCpu are buttons, then depending on which button is pressed you load the needed scene.

I hope i'v helped you. Good luck with your game !